# swift 3 - tableview cell with more textfield

Tags: macos, swift3, nstableview

I work with swift 3 for macOS and I have a tableview, which will be fill with data like this:

```
var test = ["Person 1","Person 2","Person 3"]

func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return test.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
    return ("\(test[row]) \(test[row])")
}
```

This works fine. However, how can I fill the data, if each cell has more then one textfield?

How can I assign values to the correct textfield of each cell?

In iOS there was a solution with prototype cells and custom cells.
but how will it work for macOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

First of all `NSTableView` is much more versatile than `UITableView`.

In a view based table view you can use everything as view which inherits from `NSView`. This can be a single `NSTextField` (without enclosing view) a dedicated `NSTableCellView` instance with or without additional content or a custom view with custom content.

You can also use a single column with the entire content or multiple columns.

Your data source is one-dimensional, you got only one value per row. To assign multiple values you need a model for example a custom class (a class – rather than a struct – is required to be able to use Cocoa Bindings).

Lets assume you have three columns with standard `NSTableCellView` instances.

- Create a model

  ```
  class Person {
     let firstName, lastName, email : String

     init(firstName ...
  }
  ```
- In the controller create an array with `Person` instances

  ```
  var people = [Person]()
  ```
- The method `numberOfRows` is unmodified

  ```
  func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
      return people.count
  }
  ```
- In the method `objectValueFor` just return the `Person` instance for the given row

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
      return people[row]
  }
  ```
- Now comes the macOS magic: In interface Builder open the Bindings Inspector (<kbd>⌥⌘7</kbd>) and bind the `Value` of each text field to `Table Cell View` and the `Model Key Path` to `objectValue.firstName`, `objectValue.lastName` or `objectValue.email`.

The Bindings connects the model properties dynamically to the string value of the text fields. The procedure is the same for a single column with multiple UI elements or multiple columns with a single element respectively.

Comment: one little question: is it possible to bind two values in one textfield?

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: at the moment: Textfield A > Model Key Path > objectvalue.firstname = Textfield value = first name. My wish: Textfield A > Model Key Path > objectvaule.firstname,objectvalue.secondname = Textfield value = firstname secondname

Comment: Yes, in the model declare a computed property for example `var fullName : String { return firstName + " " + lastName }` and bind this